# markup - ticks & crosses

Tags: feature-request

I really like the tick marks in some answers on [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/free-incident-management-tool-for-more-than-50-users).

However, they are being created by `imgur` images. Is it possible to expand our markup to add a green circle with a tick and a red circle with a cross (maybe a few others, like question mark)?

Maybe this could be used on some other sites, and hence should be asked at S.E meta? They probably have control over the markup anyway, rather than individual sites. Feel free to migrate this to meta-meta

Comment: E.g. on GitLab it's possible to use emoticons like `:white_check_mark:` for that. Maybe SE could consider that. But yes, that should go to the main Meta as it affects all sites.

Comment: That would be really great: 1) Make answers more visual, giving an immediate idea of how well an answer covers the requirements 2) Encourage posters to actually check all requirements.

Comment: @Izzy can you migrate this, or should I just delete & ask over there?

Comment: I'd suggest you re-ask (then link from here, and we close it then). You'd have to reword andyway (mainly removing the last paragraph, and maybe pointing to the emoticons referencing to use them like it's done at GitLab/Github – that way we'd not only have the check mark, but also others). Maybe also suggest `* [x]` as supported by Github flavored Markdown :)

Comment: Thanks, as always, Izzy. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314520/markdown-for-ticks-crosses. Feel free to delete this one (or should I?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can everyone see these Unicode symbols properly?

✅ : Yes
❌ : No

Here is how they look on Ubuntu 2018.04: [image]

Benefits:

- Visually appealing
- Faster to read
- Easier to compare
- Help make sure that answers address each requirements

On could argue that with that, bullets are not necessary anymore. But I feel that we should keep them for semantic reasons, for instance to tell search engine spiders and visual aides that it is a list.

I am looking for a "nearly" Unicode symbol but I have not found anything better than ≈ so please let me know if you know better one.

Real-world QA with these icons: [Linux pictures browser that hilights those with an EXIF location](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48685/linux-pictures-browser-that-hilights-those-with-an-exif-location)

## How to use them in your questions and answers

- Slow method that works on any OS: Copy/paste from above.
- Ubuntu: Press CTRL+SHIFT+u, release, type 2705 for Yes or 274C for No, then press SPACE.

## Example Q/A

### Question

I want a staircase calories calculator fitting these requirements:

- ✅ Configurable stair height
- ✅ Can synchronize with CaloCloud
- ✅ Gratis
- ✅ Runs on OpenZaurus

### Answer

I use Escalorus every day and I am very happy with it.

- ✅ Configurable stair height
- ✅ Can synchronize with CaloCloud
- ❌ 1 EUR
- ✅ Runs on OpenZaurus

Comment: I can see them just fine from Windows 10, with Internet Explorer 11 (sorry, company browser). You might ant to add how to insert those symbols, rather then having everyone edit your answer, just to see.  I do like the idea of retaining the lists for search engines. Good answer

Comment: The discussion continues on S.E meta, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314520/markdown-for-ticks-crosses)

Comment: Yes, this is a local ad-hoc answer while waiting for a network-wide solution... which might take years to come judging by the "status-declined" tag there :'-(

Comment: Lolx! And much appreciated it is too. Could you please edit your answer to include the Unicode values & how to insert them into an answer? Thanks

Comment: @Mawg OK, doing it now! I don't have Windows but I think there is a kind of keyboard code for easily inserting them? Would you mind testing and telling me, if you happen to have a Windows machine around?

Comment: As soon as you update the question to say how to insert Unicode, I will try it & post how it goes

Comment: @mawg: Done :-)

Comment: Alas, that's not working. Nor is [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0). I will give it a try at home this evening

Comment: @Mawg: I commented the Windows line, feel free to edit and restore it when you have time.

Answer (score 1):

I think allowing emojis (`:white_check_mark:`) like Github is not a problem.

Some solutions:

- [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) addon (browsers only)
- [Emoji to AHK](https://github.com/alexmick/emoji-to-ahk/blob/master/emoji.ahk) script (Windows only)
- AutoHotKey or PhraseExpress for specialized use. In AutoHotKey, you can use:

  ```
  :*:\check::✅
  :*:\cross::❌
  ```

  So that every time you type `\check` or `\cross` it will automatically be converted to the corresponding symbols. Remember to put it in the startup folder.